# How did the Community bot earn the "Not a Robot" badge on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, badges, community-user

Somehow, [the Community ♦ bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) [earned the "Not a Robot" badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot?userid=-1).

[image]

---

[image]

How did this happen and should I start welcoming our new robot overlords?

Comment: Seems pretty suspicious to me as well. Especially if you consider the description of this badge: "Come out and meet us and get verified as a real human" ;-)

Comment: [Why is a robot getting a badge that states it is not a robot?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335736/why-is-a-robot-getting-a-badge-that-states-it-is-not-a-robot)

Comment: You can have the Eagle Eyed Steve unofficicial badge ;p

Comment: Its a sign, skynet.. err.. community is self-aware

Comment: Umm.... lucky guess?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It was manually awarded to Community user by the Stack Overflow team, as confirmed by [Nick Craver♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335736/why-is-a-robot-getting-a-badge-that-states-it-is-not-a-robot):

> I was wondering [how long it'd take meta to notice](https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/783101082780205056). About 21 hours, not too shabby.